# I uploaded apple-app-site-association to my website root directory. Now what can I do?

Tags: ios, swift, aasa

I uploaded apple-app-site-association to my website root directory, then I checked apple-app-site-association validate from https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox. It shows all green success message. Then which is my app universal link?

Comment: the universal link is the website url. so if your website is called www.example.com then that is your universal link too. The apple-app-site-association is used to verify that you own that website/domain

Comment: Thank you sir for respond me, I did added my website url like "example.com" as it is in the Association Domain in my project capability

Comment: Then i try to hit this link in safari but it open the my website not my IOS app